# A "hobby" grade linear motor

Tags: motor

Can anyone recommend a hobbist [linear motor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_motor)?

The motors are often described as being a rolled out version of a DC motor (is that true btw). If this is the case then how does one "drive" a linear motor. I'm trying to understand what kind of signals need to be sent to the coils to make it move.

Any info welcome.

EDIT: For clarity, I'm asking about the  "stepper" type linear motor

Comment: It's effectively a stepper motor (you drive it with the same waveform). As for cheap ones, surplus is your only bet, I think. I've *never* seen them go for less than a few hundred dollars.

Comment: They are driven with with same driver as a stepper motor, really? Would that include microstep capability?

Comment: Sure, I don't see why you couldn't microstep it.

Comment: I found a 20" one in an old high-end electric typewriter.
(your requirement for 9' is a little harder to meet.)

Comment: I'm told that they can be joined to acheive virtually and unlimited length.

Comment: Very large milling machines (for example, ones made by Zimmermann) actually use rack a pinion drive systems on their axis. Lead screws are hard to get at those lengths but rack and pinions are just bolted together. You will need an anti backlash gear though, those are expensive however (Zimmermann uses a dual motor system with a driver and tension-er, no anti backlash gears but a more complex control system).

Comment: @Faken, Dual motors shouldn't be any more difficult in my solution.

Comment: @kurtnelle: Linear motors are essentially backlash free drive systems. In a dual motor, rack and pinion setup, you have two motors always pulling in opposite directions to eliminate backlash. One motor pulls harder to move in the direction you want the system to while the other pulls the opposite way to eliminate backlash and imperfections of the rack and pinion. Essentially it's an electronic version of a pretension system. The catch is when you have to switch directions. I'm way past my expertise here though, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of kinds of linear motor. Which are you referring to?

[Baldor](http://www.baldor.com/products/linear_motors.asp) makes a number of varieties, and their page has an [excellent overview](http://www.baldor.com/products/linear_motors.asp) of the different types.

I'm most familiar with linear stepper motors, which are a *type* of linear motor. However, there are Brushless DC and even AC Induction varieties.

However, I will say that they are generally as or more expensive as a comparable stepper/servo motor and lead-screw arrangement, and are much less common on the surplus market.

Given that, I think you would be better off trying to snag a long leadscrew on ebay, rather then find a similar sized linear motor. Then, just add end supports, a motor, and some linear bearings.

What are you trying to do, anyways?

Comment: Sadly, noone on ebay seems to have a 9 foot acme leadscrew, and some of the suppliers I've talked to consider that a special request. The intended purpose is for CNC Milling. Yes I know that lead screws are the dominat drive system, however I have encountred difficulties in obtaining them, and have not been successful thus far. 

Btw FakeName, what's ya real name? lol

Answer (score 1):

Any stepper with a threaded rod and captive nut will make a low speed linear motor with up to about 3 foot reach.

Comment: Yes it would but I need 9 feet.

Answer (score -1):

you can buy a central locking motor used in cars from a car spare dealer. It costs approx 5$ .
Some models have limit switches build into it. Any car with central locking will have atleast 4 motors . 1 each in each door. I am from india. We can buy one with out limit switches for 3$/ea and with limit switches at 5$/ea. The stroke distance is about 7 cm.
Sorry I will not reply for mails. or may not vist this page in the future